# xcode 4.4 link error

Tags: clang, linker-errors

I just updated xcode to 4.4.1, and I now get an link error when I build for a device. (Simulator builds are no problem). The error I get on link is

```
ld: in section __TEXT,__text reloc 10: sectionForAddress(0x2208) address not in any section for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know what this error is, or how I can get more information out of the linker?

Comment: are you targeting both armv6 and armv7?

Comment: Yes, I am targeting both armv6 and armv7

Comment: and it gives an error, when you try to run it on both the armv6 and the armv7 devices?

Comment: i am asking that because there is a known issue with XCode 4.4 and armv6. apparently it runs fine, if you are on Mountain Lion.